# If, else if loop broken

Tags: jquery, if-statement

I've just written a small if, else if loop and I get a, `unexpected token ';'` error in the console. If I remove the `;` after each `$(this).css('top', top-3"em");` statement, I get another error saying the `}` before the `else if` is unexpected!

Here's my loop, any ideas where I might have strayed?

```
$('div.result').each(function() {

    $(this).css('top', top+"em");
    top = top + 8;

    resultcount = resultcount - 1;

    if(resultcount=5) {
        $(this).css('top', top-3"em");
    } else if(resultcount=4) {
        $(this).css('top', top-7"em");
    } else if(resultcount=3) {
        $(this).css('top', top-14"em");
    } else if(resultcount=2) {
        $(this).css('top', top-20"em");
    } else(resultcount=1) {
        $(this).css('top', top-30"em");
    }

});
```

Comment: There's a bunch of syntax errors, from invalid comparison to no string concentanation.

Comment: @Borsel you're also the one that clicked on a link called **If, else if loop broken** ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have few syntax error which may need to be corrected more then on places.

- You need to use equality operator `===` instead of assignment operator `=`
- You missed the if in the last if statement.
- You have to use `+` to concatenate strings `top-3"em"` would be `(top-3)+"em"`

This is syntax error free

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/jjWgU/)**

```
$('div.result').each(function() {

    $(this).css('top', top+"em");
    top = top + 8;

    resultcount = resultcount - 1;

    if(resultcount===5) {
        $(this).css('top', (top-3)+"em");
    } else if(resultcount===4) {
        $(this).css('top', (top-7)+"em");
    } else if(resultcount===3) {
        $(this).css('top', (top-14)+"em");
    } else if(resultcount===2) {
        $(this).css('top', (top-20)+"em");
    } else if(resultcount===1) {
        $(this).css('top', top-30+"em");
    }    
});
```

Comment: Please recommend using `===` and pretend `==` does not exist.

Comment: @jbabey You're not going to make many friends if you just add that to EVERY javascript answer. There are good reasons to use `=== 0` instead of `== 0`, but not so many for using `=== 5` instead of `== 5`.

Answer (score 3):

You are setting the resultcount var, you are not checking it:

```
if(resultcount===5) {
    $(this).css('top', "top-3em");
} 
else if(resultcount===4) {
    $(this).css('top', "top-7em");
} 
else if(resultcount===3) {
    $(this).css('top', "top-14em");
} 
else if(resultcount===2) {
    $(this).css('top', top-20"em");
} 
else {
    $(this).css('top', "top-30em");
}
```

use `===` for checking the result and type.

Also there are a lot of syntax errors, try debugging them with a developer tool.

Comment: Please recommend using `===` and pretend `==` does not exist.

Answer (score 2):

Try this
You should use == instead of = inside if and you forgot to add + in each css parameter.

```
  $('div.result').each(function() {

        $(this).css('top', top + " em");
        top = top + 8;

        resultcount = resultcount - 1;

        if(resultcount ==5) {
            $(this).css('top', top-3 + "em");
        } else if(resultcount==4) {
            $(this).css('top', top-7 + "em");
        } else if(resultcount==3) {
            $(this).css('top', top-14 + "em");
        } else if(resultcount==2) {
            $(this).css('top', top-20 + "em");
        } 

    });
```

Comment: `else(resultcount==1)` should be `else if`

Comment: Whoop! Works (including the last `else if` instead of just `else` Thanks guys!